# SQL error in recurring event check

Tags: php, sql

I am making a recurring event system and have to hard code a check to see if an event has passed to make a new one. (No, I can not make a cron job because the system base is Windows and no, I do not have access to the task scheduler.)

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
require('common.php');
$query = "SELECT 
             *
          FROM 
             DD_events
      ";
try{
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$chk = $stmt->fetchall();
//print_r($chk);

foreach ($chk as $chks) {
if (time() > $chks['event_date']) {
//Add 1 day to event time
$time = strtotime($chks['event_date']);
$newTime = $time + 86400; // 24 * 60 * 60

// Create query to make the next event
    $query = "INSERT INTO
            DD_events (event_name, event_date, initiator, min_lvl, max_level)
              VALUES 
            ({$chks['event_name']}, {$newTime}, 0, {$chks['min_lvl']}, {$chks['max_level']})
      ";
    try
    {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table.
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

it returns this error:

> `Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 200)' at line 4`

Can anyone spot the error I am making because I have been looking at it for the past 30 mins and can't see it.

Comment: why did you made your query so complicated ??

Comment: Looks to me like you are missing single quotes around each of your string cols in the `VALUES()` list.

Comment: @var___ It is grabbing the info from the previous event and making a new one 1 day later.

Comment: @Matt Just a try. Check if my answer works?

Comment: Surely `event_name` must be a VARCHAR of some kind? It needs to be quoted, or better, use a parameters for the statement here and avoid this problem.  You are preparing and executing, but getting _none_ of the benefit since you're still substituting variables.

Comment: @Matt echo the second $query for us and paste it here. We need to see what it looks like. Also note you will achieve at least 300% performance improvement by running beginTransaction before the foreach and commit() after the foreach. That is because the insertions will happen as one transaction, instead of lots of separate queries. (and there is more to it, but I don't have a time to cover full ACID)

Comment: here is your echo: `INSERT INTO DD_events (event_name, event_date, initiator, min_lvl, max_level) VALUES ('DeadLands', 1357020000, 0, 150, 200)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps an easier way to do the same thing:

```
INSERT INTO DD_events
(event_name, event_date, initiator, min_lvl, max_level)
SELECT event_name, DATE_ADD(event_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY), 0, min_lvl, max_lvl
FROM DD_events
```

This will create a new event for each existing event one day later (which is what you said the code was supposed to do) and eliminates the need for basically your whole script

Comment: I tried this and it is making the date insert as `NULL`

Comment: @Matt - You mean the `event_date`? Is that a date column in your database?

Comment: Yes. It is set as DATETIME.

Comment: @Matt - Edited my answer, forgot to specify the columns in order for the insert which was probably the issue.

Comment: Why is there an `INSERT` and then `SELECT`?

Comment: @Matt - It's another way of doing an insert - you can specify that you want to insert the results of a select statement into a table.

Comment: using `$query = "INSERT INTO
                DD_events (event_name, event_date, initiator, min_level, max_level)
              SELECT
                event_name, DATE_ADD(event_date, 1 DAY), 0, min_level, max_level
              FROM
                DD_events
      ";` returns `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 DAY), 0, min_level, max_level FROM DD_events' at line 4`.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to quote your variables, but that would make your query vulnerable to sql injection, so the correct solution would be to use bound variables:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO
        DD_events (event_name, event_date, initiator, min_lvl, max_level)
          VALUES 
        (:event_name, :event_date, 0, :min_lvl, :max_level)
  ";
try
{
    // These two statements run the query against your database table.
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(':event_name' => $chks['event_name'],
                         ':event_date' => $newTime,
                         ':min_lvl' => $chks['min_lvl'],
                         ':max_level' => $chks['max_level']));
}
```

Comment: Could someone eject even if it is grabbing from another row and putting it straight back in?

Comment: @Matt It could lead to your sql breaking if for example the name column contains a `'` or a `"` character (depending on what you quote it with). Using bound variables is the best and safest way to go.

Comment: I implemented the vars into the function. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `event_name` is a `VARCHAR` you need to replace `{$chks['event_name']}` with `'{$chks['event_name']}'`. Depending on the data type, this might hold true also for `event_date`